# Setting a dynamic center with google map's api

Tags: reactjs

```
class SimpleMap extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    static defaultProps = {
        center: {lat: 40.73, lng: -73.93},
        zoom: 12
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
                <GoogleMapReact
                    bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: API_KEY}}
                    defaultCenter={this.props.center}
                    defaultZoom={5}
                >
                    <AnyReactComponent
                        lat={this.props.lat}
                        lng={this.props.long}
                        text=" the ISS"
                    />
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </div>
        );
    }
} 
export default SimpleMap;
```

I have a location being supplied by an API that I wish to display on google maps by centring onto the long and lat coordinates that I have on the parent. when I change the static defaultProps to use props 'this.props.lat/long' it won't render the map unless I hard code my lat and long.

any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Have `lat/long` as a part of react state. So when ever it gets updated, the component will re render

Comment: Thank you @upog seem's to have solved it.